# Android UnresolvedHostException on real device using servername

Tags: android, web-services, dns, httpwebrequest

Hi I am developing an application which is connected to a cooperate network via a VPN-connection.
Now I have the following problem:

If I try to send a HTTP-Request from a real device to a server located in the network using the server-name the logcat shows an **UnresolvedHostException**.
If I am using the IP of the server instead everything works fine as expected.

*On the emulator the problem does not appear at all and everything works.*

So I tested this on the browser of my device and the browser seems to have the same problem, using the IP, the browser can access the server, but if I use the server-name the browser returns a 404 error.

Does anyone have a clue why this problem is appearing or can give me a hint how to solve this issue, I have searched the web but cannot find a proper solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having the same problem, **shutdown your device** wait a moment so it totally powers of and then restart it, this solves the problem and saves you a lot of time, stress and rage, it seems like their is a bug in the system (at least on some API versions)